# Fixed margin for legend in Plotly Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, legend

I have a dynamic size of plot in plotly, depending on number of bars:
[image]

I use such parametrization for legend position:

```
fig.update_layout(
        bargap=0.1,
        barmode='stack',
        yaxis={
            'side': 'right',
        },
        yaxis2={
            'title': 'PSI',
            'anchor': 'free',
            'overlaying': 'y',
            'side': 'left',
        },
        legend={
            'x': 1.1,
        },
        **layout_params,
    )
```

But there is a problem of different gaps between plot and legend while using different widths:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to make fixed gap without relative calculation?

Comment: When can you get like the second plot?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a fixed bar width and bar gap and change figure width dynamically according to the resulting number of bars on the final plot. Additionally, you can add to the conditional statement number of bars that has to be exceeded in order to start changing figure size dynamically etc. But the easiest way would be to move the legend itself below the plot ;)

PS Consider using `matplotlib` and looking at [How can I fix the space between a plot and legend so that new text doesn't change the spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712253/how-can-i-fix-the-space-between-a-plot-and-legend-so-that-new-text-doesnt-chang)